# Material-ui style dialog / modal backdrop

Tags: css, typescript, material-ui, jss, react-tsx

How do I go about styling the transparent dark overlay of a material-ui dialog or modal?
I'm using material-ui/React/Typescript.

[image]

Instead of a transparent dark, I want it to be a transparent white.
I'd prefer a [JSS](https://cssinjs.org) solution but an inline style is welcomed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `BackdropProps` property of the modal:

```
<Modal
          aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
          aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          BackdropProps= {{
              classes: {
                  root: classes.backDrop
              }
          }}
        >
```

and in your style object:

```
...
backDrop: {
    background: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

The API for this has changed a bit in the last couple of years. `BackdropProps` is now referenced by `slotProps.backdrop`. Meaning the component now takes a `slotProps` prop, that receives an object, one of the properties being `backdrop` all lowercase. `backdrop` takes an object that can include many things, including a `style` prop that you use like usual.

```js
    <Modal
      slotProps={{ backdrop: { style: { backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)' } } }}
    >
    </Modal>
```