# How to target backdrop color property of Material UI Dialog using styled components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking to change the color of the backdrop of the `Dialog` component of Material UI using styled-components.

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284222/material-ui-style-dialog-modal-backdrop) on how to do exactly that but I'm not sure how to apply this to styled-components.

I currently haved a `StyledDialog` as such:

```
const StyledDialog = styled(Dialog).attrs({

  classes: { paper: 'container' },
  keepMounted: true,
  'aria-labelledby': 'alert-dialog-slide-title',
  'aria-describedby': 'alert-dialog-slide-description'
})`
  .container {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can reference the [backdrop](https://material-ui.com/api/backdrop/#css) via its global class ("MuiBackdrop-root") in the following manner:

```
const StyledDialog = styled(Dialog)`
  .MuiBackdrop-root {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
`;
```

[image: Edit styled-components Dialog backdrop]

Relevant Styled Components documentation: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting

Answer (score 19):

`<Dialog BackdropProps={{style: {backgroundColor: 'white'}}}/>`

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Dialog/Dialog.js

Comment: this answer should be the selected answer!

Comment: Nice one! Simple and easy

Comment: The prop is now deprecated, see the solution by @htmn.

Answer (score 5):

`BackdropProps` are now [deprecated](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog/#props), you can use `componentsProps.backdrop` instead

```
<Dialog componentsProps={{ backdrop: { style: { backgroundColor: "transparent" } } }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update, according to the doc v5.14.20 :

> It's recommended to use the `slotProps` prop instead, as `componentsProps` will be deprecated in the future.

Here is an example `slotProps={{ backdrop: { timeout: 600, style: { backgroundColor: "#000"}}}}`